# Obtener archivos de un virtual machine de google cloud en un google colaboratory notebook

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colab

Tengo archivos en una máquina virtual alojada y creada en Google Cloud y quiero poder acceder a ellos en google colab para ejecutar selenium.

¿Están los archivos almacenados en el almacenamiento de Google? Si es el caso, he encontrado un tutorial [allí](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-access-files-from-google-cloud-storage-in-colab-notebooks-8edaf9e6c020), me muestra cómo acceder a archivos de Google Cloud Storage en Colab Notebooks

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta es: GCS no es el sistema de almacenamiento usado por tu máquina virtual.

Tu máquina virtual usa [Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks) para almacenar sus archivos.

Para copiar archivos a Google Cloud Storage debes usar [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) u otra herramienta similar.